# Is it possible to customize a JTree Node?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jtree, treecellrenderer

I want to try to implement a tree like this:
Each node of the tree is a self defined component,which is composed of a JComboBox and a JTextField. Each time I select an item in the JComboBox, this node will generate three new sub nodes as leaves.

Is it possible to do that? I have tried using the TreeCellRender, but it seems that it just paints the combobox and the textfield, but the combobox is not selectable.

Comment: For editing, you need an editor as well. Then this is certainly possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is editing the `JTree`. For this a renderer is not sufficient. Renderers are only used to 'render' the `JTree`, so are only sufficient if you have a read-only `JTree`.

If you want to edit the model behind the `JTree` as well, you have to set an editor on it.

The reason that your combobox is not selectable is explained in the Swing table tutorial, in [the part about renderers and editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). The same applies for trees (but that tutorial does not contain such a section).